# python module autopep8 problem in Linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, autopep8

I run ubuntu by wsl 2. I use python 3.10 version. Now when I run autopep8 the problem of your below picture comes. How can it be fixed?
when I type autopep8 --in-place -a filename.py ,this problem appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/asib/.local/bin/autopep8", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4518, in main
    results = fix_multiple_files(args.files, args, sys.stdout)
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4413, in fix_multiple_files
    ret = _fix_file((name, options, output))
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 4383, in _fix_file
    return fix_file(*parameters)
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 3569, in fix_file
    original_source = readlines_from_file(filename)
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 195, in readlines_from_file
    with open_with_encoding(filename) as input_file:
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 172, in open_with_encoding
    encoding = detect_encoding(filename, limit_byte_check=limit_byte_check)
  File "/home/asib/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autopep8.py", line 182, in detect_encoding
    from lib2to3.pgen2 import tokenize as lib2to3_tokenize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib2to3'
```

I want when I give autopep8 command, it will work.
For example: autopep8 --in-place -a filename.py

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.